# Recursive async with and without sleep

Tags: javascript

I have two versions of an async function

```
async function asyncRecurseOne(i){
    try{
        console.log(i)
        i = i +1;
        await asyncRecurseOne(i)
    }catch(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    }
}

asyncRecurseOne(0);
```

which results in maximum call stack size exceeded at around number 6300

```
6246
6247
6248
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at asyncRecurseOne (/home/amit/Projects/NodeJs/MJS/recurse.js:38:17)
    at asyncRecurseOne (/home/amit/Projects/NodeJs/MJS/recurse.js:36:15)
```

Now in another version, I do the following using a sleep method

```
let sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
async function asyncRecurseTwo(i){
    try{
        console.log(i)
        i = i +1;
        await sleep(100);
        await asyncRecurseTwo(i)
    }catch(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

And this function does not give the maximum call stack size to reach the issue, I ran on my system till number 20000 was logged.

How does the second function keep executing without reaching the maximum stack size issue?

Comment: I'm assuming that in the second example the maximum call stack size was not exceeded. --- Also the first example has no reason to be async.

Comment: No @evolutionxbox in asyncRecurseTwo the call stack size was not exceeded,  i checked till value of i became 20000

Comment: That's what I said...

Comment: you don't even need `sleep` here. `await 0;` will prevent call stack fill up and make the site unresponsive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`async` functions execute synchronously, up until the point they hit an `await`, at which point they return a promise. Your first piece of code has its only await on this line:

```
await asyncRecurseOne(i)
```

To evaluate this line, it needs to call `asyncRecurseOne`, get the return value, and only then will it `await`. So it will synchronously recurse, and that next time through the function will do the same thing, building a bigger and bigger call stack until you get the exception. It never makes it to the `await`.

Your other case doesn't have this problem. It makes it to this line:

```
await sleep(100);
```

And sleep creates and returns a promise. Then it hits the `await`, and so your function returns a promise of its own. No increasing call stack. 100 milliseconds later, it resumes and recurses, but this new recursion has the same interruption and so the callstack doesn't keep growing.

Comment: **Very** well observed! (And succinctly but clearly explained.)

Comment: Nicholas, Can you explain the second part in detail, especially this line
" 100 milliseconds later, it resumes and recurses, but this new recursion has the same interruption and so the callstack doesn't keep growing."

Comment: In 100 milliseconds, the setTimeout goes off. This starts a brand new call stack. It resolves the promise from `sleep`, which then queues up a microtask to run asyncRecurseTwo starting at the `await`. asyncRecurseTwo then calls itself, so now there's two instances of asyncRecursetwo on the call stack. This second one calls sleep, creates a promise, and then awaits that promise. Having hit an await, execution stops and the call stack empties. Repeat 100 milliseconds later.

Comment: Can you provide a reference detailing why the "call stack empties" after "execution stops"? It still needs to retain the information in each layer of the recursive calls, so I don't see why it can handle it better when it waits for an async function. When making a new branch of execution, does it take the existing stack and write it to disk or something, before proceeding with the rest in memory?